# "Loading" div with a spinner while another function takes place in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

stackoverflow

I have an ASP project where I am managing the client side with jQuery, which I recently took on learning.

My project loads a ~400 row table unto a GridView. The table can afterwards be filtered.

The way that I am handling the variables on which the filtering depends on is probably not the most efficient, because filtering takes quite a lot of time. For now, however, I have not come up with another way to label my rows.

Anyway, I want to show a "Loading" div with a spinner while the table is being filtered (which is just adding and removing a hiddenRow class to the filtered items).

I tried to handle this with the following line:

```
$('#loading').fadeIn().promise().done(function(){
      //the whole filtering function
});
```

This code effectively shows the loading div, but my spinner never spins until the whole table is filtered, defeating the purpose of the div. The div shows, the spinner is frozen, the table is filtered for some seconds, and only after the filtering is finished (memory is released?) the spinning starts.

What are my choices here? I thought about using a Worker because of some videos I saw, but I am using **jquery-1.8.3** (this is work related and the browsers are **IE8-**) and I think it is not supported. Another answer suggested a purely CSS spinner, which sounds really nice but isn't supported either. I know I am really limited by the tools, but is there anything I can do?

Comment: do you make jquery ajax call while filtering rows ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
// queue the filtering function after spinner appears
$('#loading').fadeIn().queue(function() {
      filteringFunction().done(function() {
          // remove the spinner, do other stuff
          // this will execute when the filteringFunction is complete
      });
});

// use jQuery.Deferred() to synchronize the actions after filtering completes
function filteringFunction() {
     var status = $.Deferred();

     ... // the whole filtering function
     status.resolve(); // set this value when your logic is complete

     return status;
}
```

Comment: The Visual Studio IntelliSense does not fetch a 'done' function for my filter function

Comment: I don't us VS so can't comment on that. But did you try running the code? You can read about deferred.done here: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: I will try it and get back to you, then! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show loading image keep an div in the master page and create a global jquery hook for ajax call as below

```
<div id="waitImageDiv" >
add your image or message here
</div>

//Global hook-up - show "please wait" when any ajax call is made in the application
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#waitImageDiv').show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#waitImageDiv').hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it never triggers. I don't think I am using an ajax calls. I don't understand what making an ajax call really means, but my filtering functions are just getting jQuery objects through selectors and adding and removing classes.